# Code to be working in code a and b

Tags: c#, html, regex

This regex code `v>Fant <strong>(.+?) treff</strong> på ditt søk<`

works for the code a

```
<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" align=\"center\"><tr><td><div id=\"boxhit\"><div>
<div>Fant <strong>12 treff</strong> på ditt søk</div></div></div></td></tr></table></div>
```

but not this code b

```
<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" align=\"center\"><tr><td><div id=\"boxhit\"><div>
<div>Fant <strong>1 162 treff</strong>, viser de 100 første</div></div></div></td></tr></table></div>
```

I don't know what part I need to add in order to change in order to regex code to be working for code a and b.

Use http://regexstorm.net/tester in order to test the code.

Comment: Remove the ` på ditt søk< ` part ?

Comment: .NET regex tester? Are you using the pattern in a C# environment?

Comment: Please tag the question with the relevant programming language/technology you are using. (In any case, I'm sure that language provides a proper DOM parser so you don't need to mess with regular expressions.)

Comment: Which part you need to capture?

Comment: The code is used in C#

Comment: @KLN: Then it would be more appropriate to use HtmlAgilityPack to grab the DIV's first child (STRONG) and then access its value that would be a plain string that you could easily run regexps on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `v>Fant <strong>(.+?) treff</strong>(.*?)<` to catch both texts.

Because you specifically tested on `på ditt søk`, your regex didn't match `, viser de 100 første`.

Answer (score 0):

this part:    `treff</strong> på ditt søk<`
does not exist in code B. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm right? You needed this to capture digits?

```
<strong>(.*) treff
```